# C++ sort linked list in ascending order

Tags: c++

This is my code.I am wondering that why it doesn't work.

```
sll_node *sortList(sll_node *head)
{

 int temp=head->value;
 if(head!=NULL||temp>head->next->value)
 {
     head->value=head->next->value;
     head->next->value=temp;
 }
 else
 {
    sortList(head->next);
    sortList(head->next->next);
    sortList(head->next);
 }        
  return head;
}
```

Comment: Can you please specify what you mean by **" it doesn't work. "**

Comment: Please use a debugger. The problems in the above code aren't too esoteric. Running through a small list and and `sortList`s operation on it will show you the answer.

Comment: Or just start adding print statements, that should be enough to figure this out. And you're checking for `NULL` *after* you've already dereferenced `head`.

Comment: So if there are at least two nodes... you swap the first two values, then return. And you're wondering why this doesn't work?

Answer (score 0):

The main problem in the code you have shown is that you are using pointers before knowing if they are valid.

So before you can assign temp to head->value or use head->next, you have to make sure head does not equal NULL. Before you use head->next->value or head->next->next, you have to make sure head->next is not equal to NULL.

Try this:

```
sll_node *sortList(sll_node *head)
{
    if(head != NULL)
    {
        int temp=head->value;
        if (head->next != NULL)
        {
            if (temp > head->next->value)
            {
                head->value=head->next->value;
                head->next->value=temp;
            }
            else
            {
                sortList(head->next);
            }
        }
    }
    return head;
}
```

There is another problem that you will run into after you run this.

If your list is: [3, 2, 1, 4]
The first pass through sort list will make: [2, 3, 1, 4]
The second pass will result in: [2, 1, 3, 4]
The third and final pass will result in: [2, 1, 3, 4]

I'll let you try and solve this next step. I'll answer specific questions if you have them once you've put some more effort in.